# Opening/starting a specific Android activity passing an intent parameter from the browser

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am developing an Android application and a website. What I am trying to do now is that I like to open the specific activity of Android application from the browser when the user click on a link.

This is my Android activity class

```
class SphereViewerActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sphere_viewer)
        intent.getStringExtra("image_url")

    }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I am getting the image_url parameter from the browser. Is it possible to open that activity passing the parameter from the JavaScript or browser?

I found the solution, it is to have the link like this

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

But how can I pass intent data as parameter?

I tried adding the app links. not working when I click Test App Links

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 4 options to achieve what you want:

1. Deep Links
2. Android App Links
3. Firebase Dynamic Links
4. Firebase App Indexing

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53129005/1631967) to see more descriptions about them.

In simplest approach (Deep Links), you can introduce your `Activity` as a handler of specific pattern `URL`s and pass the desired parameters as `URL` query params.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SphereViewerActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp://zxing" -->
        <data android:host="zxing" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**SphereViewerActivity.kt**

```
class SphereViewerActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sphere_viewer)

        if (intent != null && intent.action == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
            intent.data?.apply{
                if (getQueryParameter("image_url") != null && getQueryParameter("image_url").isNotEmpty()) {
                    val imageUrl = data.getQueryParameter ("image_url") as String
                    // do what you want to do with imageUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Your html snippet:**

```
<a href="myapp://zxing?image_url=some_image_url"> Take a QR code </a>
```

Comment: I tried adding app links. Even if I set up with the right details and test the link with the right details, not working. Please, check the question edited please?

Comment: Ok, your issue is able to solve with simple deep link. I've updated the answer.